# warning C4552: '<' : operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2010

I have a bunch of loops in my programs. the lines that I get these errors on are the following:

```
for (size_t i=0; i++;i<student.length())
```

and

```
for (int i=0; i++; i<13)
```

Can't seem to figure it out :/ i made the iterative variable in the first loop of type size_t because the .length function returns size_t variables (or so the internet says).  even if that's the problem, i can't see why I would get the error on the second loop.

Comment: Look into how to write for loops again.

Comment: Your loops look pretty funky - are you sure those expressions are in the right order?

Comment: You have the parameters in the wrong order.

Comment: For(From This; While This Is True; Do This;) Though after a few it's just "nature"

Answer (score 6):

You have the termination condition and the action flipped, this:

```
for (size_t i=0; i++;i<student.length())
```

should be:

```
for (size_t i=0;i<student.length(); i++)
```

and the same issue for the second `for` loop as well. This is useful [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for).

Comment: omg kill me i'm an idiot. thank you both for the help !!

Answer (score 2):

The terms are in the wrong order. It needs to be

`for(int i=0; i<13; i++);`